# ¿Cómo puedo usar un proxi en un script de python?

Tags: python, session, socket, python-requests, proxy

Quisiera saber cual seria el método para usar un proxi en un script de Python. la verdad estoy requiriéndolo para varias cosas, una de ella es que heroku no proporciona una dirección ip estática, y la app que estoy diseñando inicia un servidor con socket el cual me obliga que use la dirección ip estática para que los clientes que se conecten puedan tener acceso al servidor, y estos clientes también deben conectarse al servidor con la dirección ip estática que les suministra el servidor.

Y la segunda es que requiero realizar peticiones con el modulo requests con un proxi, y deseo que esa session de la solicitud se mantenga viva para seguir usando la misma session. he visto que con requests.session() puedo crear la session pero mi pregunta sigue siendo como usar el proxi en cualquier script implementado con python.

Answer (score 1):

El request busca entre  las variables de entorno las siguientes: `HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, <schema>__PROXY`, donde  `<schema>`  es ftp,http,etc. (mayusculas o minusculas). Si las encuentra las utiliza para salir por el URL indicado por estas variables.

El formato es el siguiente:

```
<schema>_PROXY=<scheme>://[usuario:password]@<url>:[port]
```

El usuario y password es por si el proxy necesita autenticación.

Por otro, también lo puedes hacer por script.Para ello primero defines un diccionario con los schemas que tienen proxy, por ejemplo, para definir un proxy para el ftp, http y https:

```
proxies = {'ftp':  '<url del proxy>',
           'http': '<url del proxy>',
           'https':'<url del proxy>',
           }
```

El <url_proxy> tiene el mismo formato indicado para las variables de entorno.

Luego lo puedes utiliza con el request:

```
import requests


r = requests.get(<url>, proxies=proxies)
```

Si quieres utilizar `Session`:

```
from requests import Session


session = Session()


r = session.get(
            proxies=proxies,
            url=<url>
            )


r = session.post(
    proxies=proxies,
    url=<url>,
    data= <params>,
    }
)
```

Las variables de entorno aplican para cualquier proyecto o script Python de equipo.